# Add more option in PrintDialog for print like print through microsoft word,paint in C# winForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

This is my code

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.AllowSomePages = true;
            
            pdoc = new PrintDocument();
            PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 15);
            PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custom", 100, 200);
            //ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
            pd.Document = pdoc;
            pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
            //pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height =320;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 820;

            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 520;
           
            pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);

            DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PrintPreviewDialog pp = new PrintPreviewDialog();
                pp.Document = pdoc;
                //pp.Dispose();
                result = pp.ShowDialog();
                
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pdoc.Print();
                }
            }
```

I am using C# winform application. My code printing perfectly but giving less option to print has shown in image I want to add more option like microsoft word,paint. Anyone have idea for that please tell me.

[image]

Comment: Adding Word and Paint doesn't makes sense because those are applications and are not virtual printers. You can create and install your virtual printer, then it will show in the printers list.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response I am going to try virtual printer.